# Find the series for $e^{-x}$ (By differentiation of $e^x$)

Tags: power-series

> Given that $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$
>
> Find the series for $e^{-x}$
>
> Note: derive the series for $e^{-x}$ showing your own working.

Trying to work out some questions from my textbook, I don't even know where to start. Help

Comment: "Derive" is different from "differentiation". To "derive" the series for $e^{-x}$ one could substitute $-x$ in for $x$ in the series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that will help you out a lot:

If $f(x)=e^x$, and $f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}...$

Then $f(-x)=e^{-x}$. How does that affect the power series?

Comment: So, does this look right to you?    

$f(-x)=e^x$$=1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}...$

Comment: @ElliottHawkins no. $(-x)^2=x^2$, and so on. So the $-$ and $+$ will alternate.

Comment: @Botond ohhh, right got it. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Substitute $-x$ instead of $x$.